# UITableViewCell separator insets 0 not exactly to left border?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I wonder why if i set (in storyboard custom separator insets left = 0, right = 0) why there is still space on the left side and it is not exactly to the left border?

As you can see, right side is exactly at border.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this in your code and run the project.
[image]

Comment: You must wellcome

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

Add this where you are declaring your table view

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
// Set seperator to start from zero
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
    [self.tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
```

And add this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
```